# Multi column menu change Width in Wordpress?

Tags: drop-down-menu, wordpress

i have created multi column drop down  menu my site looking Like this  .  My site url : [Site Url](http://watchedge.com/)

in my Site watch watches Branded is there  if click watch brand showing drop down . empty black area is there. now question Remove empty black area in Watches drop-down menu ? please any idea about ?